# Should I submit my paper to a journal that accepts papers quickly?

Tags: journals, computer-science, publishers, disreputable-publishers

Should I submit my paper to a journal that accepts quickly?

One of my batch-mate got accepted in a [journal](http://www.mecs-press.org/ijigsp/) within 1 month. The journal was also listed on **predatory journal's list**.

Please advise.

Comment: Usually not, but only because most reputable journals take some time to review papers...

Comment: i'd say no, just by looking at the journal you linked. Without naming any, there are few recent papers that are very weak, where they use a very simple, out of the box algorithm for simple applications, that would never be published in any reputable journals due to it being more of a simple engineering project and not contributing to new science. I am just a random dude in the internet, so take my advice as you will (I may be wrong)

Comment: Counter-question: Should I use the steam driven high-speed printing press from 1811 only because it is faster and cheaper? Yes, because it helps to distribute knowledge to more people.

Comment: After looking at few article, I told myself to stay at least 100miles away from this journal (and the publisher).

Answer (score 37):

Quick acceptance (a month) is pretty surprising for many disciplines, but that's not necessarily a bad thing in itself. But if the journal "guarantees quick acceptance", you should be very suspicious, since reputable journals do not bother with any rhetoric in that direction.

Being listed as a predatory journal is a very negative indicator... though, if we are scrupulous, we should note that those lists do not pretend to be infallible.

On the whole, I'd be suspicious. Better to go with well-known journals that do not promise such stuff.

Answer (score 22):

The time between submission and publication is not a good metric of the quality of a journal. Some journals may be both reputable, and specifically designed for rapid communications. For example, in the field of Optics, there is a journal called [Optics Express](https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/journal/oe/about.cfm). This journal is well regarded, has a median turn around of 65 days (so approximately half of the papers are accepted in less than two months) and an impact factor above 3. There are many other reputable journals across many fields specifically designed to rapidly publish. This does not mean the review process is compromised.

A journal listed as being predatory is an entirely separate matter, and a far more important metric to consider when looking to publish. Personally, I would **never** consider publishing in such a journal because you cannot guarantee that your research has been correctly reviewed, which then casts a shadow over whether your research is worthy of publication. This may have negative consequences for your down the line when applying for jobs (depending on the career path you choose).

The best (safest) approach is to only submit to reputable journals, and to continue to work on your research until such time as it is suitable for such a journal. Given you have tagged your question with [student](/questions/tagged/student), you may also want to ask your lecturers and other faculty staff what an appropriate student focused journal would be.

Comment: Great point, many journals exist for the purpose of rapid publication. These are often highly reputed and have high rejection ratios.

Answer (score 4):

Only you can answer this question, because only you know what you want out of the publication. Just remember: balancing the upside of quick review and likely acceptance are downsides such as 1) you are less likely to receive detailed reviewer comments, and 2) it might do less good to your career if others identify it's a predatory journal, and might even be harmful.

I suggest reading articles such as [this one](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/30/science/predatory-journals-academics.html) and coming to your own conclusions about the costs vs. benefits. Ultimately, it's your paper and your decision.

Answer (score 3):

You have your name to protect. Try to ensure the most trustworthy journals and peers endorse your work for publication.

- The time before acceptance does not necessarily mean that the standard procedures for accepting a good paper are violated.

There are papers that have been accepted on initial review and they have been well received by the research community.

Answer (score 2):

NO! Absolutely not.  If the journal is on a predatory list, and people realize this, it will be held against you in many circumstances, v.g. scholarship applications, job applications etc.

It’s one thing to avoid journal where the process is extremely long, but usually it does not pay to shortcut the process and trade time for poor reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer: absolutely not - look at their Editorial board.

Long answer: a key indicator of the quality of the journal is the level of people at the journal's Editorial board. If you check the Editorial board of this particular journal, http://www.mecs-press.org/ijigsp/board.html, you will see that the people there belong to some obscure universities. Austin Peay State University, West Pomeranian University of Technology, KLE Technological University, Al Azhar University and so on and so force. I didn't find anyone from a "normal" place.

It means that your article won't get a reasonable referee and most likely will not be noticed by the scientific community. I strongly recommend to select another, normal journal for publishing your research.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to publishing papers, quality is much much more important than quantity. I would rather have 1 paper in a top tier conference, rather than 100 in some easy workshops.

Having too many papers in junk venues is definitely career suicide. When people look at your publication record, and cannot recognize any conference/workshops that you have been published, nobody will ever care about what you do.

Comment: Unless you apply for whatever and they use things like the H-index and it's 1...